# Writing to memory mapped VGA at 0x000B8000 doesn't print characters

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

If I use:

```
mov ah, 0x00
mov al, 0x03
int 0x10
```

to set the video mode and then:

```
mov dword [0xb8000], 0x0769
```

to print a character to VGA buffer it doesn't do anything.

Is the information I'm getting from websites too old? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I suppose you are programming in real mode under DOS or something.  Note that as segmentation is active, you cannot just linearly address memory.  You have to form a suitable segment/offset pair (e.g. `b800:0000`), load a segment register with the segment and then load from the address referencing the appropriate segment register.

Comment: It should be noted that according to the OP in another comment, the `int 0x10` part is done in real mode to switch video modes and that at some later point after they enter protected mode when they write to the video memory.

Comment: Are you testing this on real hardware or on a real PC? If it fails on real hardware you may have encountered hardware that no longer supports writing characters to 0xb8000 to render text (although it will work via int 10h BIOS calls). If it fails on an emulator there may be a problem with how you have set up protected mode.

Comment: @Michael, I’ve never encountered any hardware that doesn’t support this.

Comment: @prl : I have and so have others. We've discussed such hardware over on the OSDev forums. Such hardware is more recent. The hardware uses a frame buffer for displaying text. The frame buffer isn't actually at 0xb8000 . If you write to that area nothing happens. If you use the BIOS (provided by some CSM) text will display because some of these BIOSes  emulates drawing characters by writing the fonts to the frame buffer.

Comment: One piece of hardware in particular was a Chromebook 3.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I wonder why they didn't do it right and set up paging with a page fault handler that would update the frame buffer on writes to the `b800` segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offset in real mode is limited to 0xFFFF. This is not a flat 32-bit address space that we know and love.  Assembling your code with NASM 2.14.02 produces this machine code (with `ndisasm` disassembly shown):

```
66 C7 06 0080 69070000   mov dword [0x8000],0x769
******************       warning: word data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
```

If your version of NASM or whatever assembler you're using didn't warn you that you were making this mistake, update it or use the warning options it does have.

---

#### What do do instead

Instead, set ES to 0xB800 and use it as the segment:

```
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
mov word [es: 0], 0x0769
```

On a side note, a single screen character in text mode corresponds to a WORD in video memory, not a DWORD. A byte for the character, another byte for attributes.

---

If you were trying to override the *address* size instead of the operand-size, to use a DWORD address with an address-size prefix: that's possible but won't do what you want.  The segment limit is still 64k.  But just for the record, the NASM syntax is

```
mov  word [dword 0xb8000], 0x0769      ; will #GP fault because of segment limit
; 67 C7 05 00800B00 6907
```

Comment: I suppose the assembler generates a `67` address size override and uses a 32 bit addressing mode.  Not that that would lift the segment limit.

Comment: @fuz: If you do something like that in real mode (use a 32-bit address to exceed the 64 KiB segment limits) you will get a general protection fault; and (sadly) the BIOS in a lot of computers will assume its an "IRQ 5", do nothing useful, then return to the instruction that caused the exception (which will cause another exception), leading to an infinite loop (which probably looks the same as "the write did nothing" to OP given that most beginners use a "loop forever because I haven't written more code yet" to make their boot code stop).

Comment: Thanks it worked except it should be mov word [es:0], 0x0769. In NASM syntax at least.

Comment: @fuz: I tried it with NASM since the OP is using NASM syntax: I got `66 C7 06 0080 69070000   mov dword [0x8000],0x769`, and NASM also printed `warning: word data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]`.  Possibly older NASM doesn't default to enabling that warning, or the OP ignored it...

Comment: @user123: I tagged your question with NASM and changed this answer from MASM to NASM syntax.  (`word ptr` is MASM-style, like GNU `.intel_syntax` and actual MASM).  I also added some stuff which could be a separate answer if Seva wants.  Most importantly, don't ignore assembler warnings.  And if NASM didn't warn you about this, enable `-Wall` or upgrade to a better NASM version if that's not sufficient.

Comment: Actually, I didn't get any warning since I was trying to print to VGA from protected mode in which there is no bound limit at 0xFFFF. I'm a beginner so I can't tell about everything you said but this answer works in 16 bits real mode and gives me a good lead so I marked it as accepted.

Comment: Of course if you take advantage of the limit field in the descriptor cache and increase the data segment limits to 4GiB rather than 64Kib (also known as [unreal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode)) then you could use `mov word [dword 0xb8000],0x769`

Comment: @user123 If you have trouble doing this in protected mode, it might be interesting to post a [mcve] of what you actually did (including minimal code to set up protected mode) and we may try to figure it out together.  But please go ahead and make a new question for that.